# Navigation JSON coming from cache even after disabling service caching

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-1.5, dxa-net

I can see the logs in log file that the navigation.json file is coming from Cache, but we have disabled the serivce-caching completely in Web.Config.
Please suggest where I can look more on this.

```
2019-05-02 08:06:52,254 [27] DEBUG - Deserializing Navigation Model from raw content URL '/en/navigation.json'
2019-05-02 08:06:52,291 [27] DEBUG - Obtained Navigation Model from cache.
2019-05-02 08:06:52,296 [27] DEBUG - Obtained Navigation Model from cache.
2019-05-02 08:06:52,296 [27] DEBUG - Obtained Navigation Model from cache.
```

Comment: maybe still CIL cache enabled?

Comment: Can you please point me to exact file, where I can check this?

Comment: The `service-caching` app setting in Web.config controls CIL caching.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually observe caching issues, or are you just worried by these DEBUG messages?

These messages are logged at line #215 here: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/1.5/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Mapping/DefaultProvider.cs

As you can see, the caching happens in `HttpContext.Items`, so this is a very short-lived (request lifetime) cache which cannot be disabled through configuration.

In later DXA versions, Navigation Models are cached through a general, configurable caching mechanism.

BTW: What is the reason for disabling CIL caching (`service-caching` app setting) altogether?  I definitely wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: When we disable this caching setting, the navigation JSON is coming up updated, otherwise, it was not coming updated only for one language(en), out of three. We tried this, and it worked on lower environment, but haven't disabled it on Production, as disabling it is impacting performance.

Comment: It means that service-caching has nothing to do in the caching on Navigation Model.